# How to deserialise JSON string to object relaxing root value case sensitivity?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, json-deserialization

Facing issue while moving my project from `Jersey` to `Spring MVC`.
How to relax case insensitivity for root value in `Jackson`?

**I would like to support both upper and lower case.**

We have below `Jackson` configurations which works fine for properties and enums but not for root value

```
spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-properties=true
spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-enums=true
```

In my case, I do not have access to `Car` class and hence can not use any of the `Jackson` annotations like `@JsonRootValue` to update the name of `Car` class to 'car'

Here is the sample class with test to reproduce the issue, I am facing.

Wouldn't it be nice to have configuration to relax root name in jackson library?

```
public class CarTest {

    public class Car {
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testCarRootValueCaseSensitivity() throws IOException {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setName("audi");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        String carAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(car);
        System.out.println(carAsString);

        // Works fine with out any exception as the root value Car has captital 'C'
        objectMapper.readValue("{\"Car\":{\"name\":\"audi\"}}", Car.class);

        // Throws exception when lower case 'c' is provided than uppercase 'C'
        objectMapper.readValue("{\"car\":{\"name\":\"audi\"}}", Car.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES works for property values but not for root value

Comment: May be you should you 
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya Problem is not with un wrapping, problem id with case sensitivity for root value.

Comment: You can try to use `MixIn` feature and declare root type name using extra class or interface. Take a look on examples: [Jackson conditional @JsonUnwrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425419/jackson-conditional-jsonunwrapped/25435990#25435990), [Custom Jackson Serializer for a specific type in a particular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252918/custom-jackson-serializer-for-a-specific-type-in-a-particular-class/23255539#23255539)

Comment: @MichałZiober In my case, I want to support both cases. If I use MixIn, I will not be able to support both

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: I am using 2.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a look on exception which is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Root name 'car' does not match expected ('Car') for type [simple type, class com.example.Car]
 at [Source: (String)"{"car":{"name":"audi"}}"; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.example.Car["car"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportPropertyInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1477)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportPropertyInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1493)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._unwrapAndDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:4286)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4200)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3173)
```

you can notice `_unwrapAndDeserialize` method name.

In this method you can find this piece of code:

```
String actualName = p.getCurrentName();
if (!expSimpleName.equals(actualName)) {
   ctxt.reportPropertyInputMismatch(rootType, actualName,
       "Root name '%s' does not match expected ('%s') for type %s",
       actualName, expSimpleName, rootType);
}
```

There is no way to configure this behaviour since always `equals` method is used.

If you really want to parse it with case insensitive mode you can override `_unwrapAndDeserialize` method and replace `equals` with `equalsIgnoreCase`. Example class:

```
class CaseInsensitiveObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    protected Object _unwrapAndDeserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, DeserializationConfig config, JavaType rootType, JsonDeserializer<Object> deser) throws IOException {
        PropertyName expRootName = config.findRootName(rootType);
        // 12-Jun-2015, tatu: Should try to support namespaces etc but...
        String expSimpleName = expRootName.getSimpleName();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            ctxt.reportWrongTokenException(rootType, JsonToken.START_OBJECT,
                    "Current token not START_OBJECT (needed to unwrap root name '%s'), but %s",
                    expSimpleName, p.getCurrentToken());
        }
        if (p.nextToken() != JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            ctxt.reportWrongTokenException(rootType, JsonToken.FIELD_NAME,
                    "Current token not FIELD_NAME (to contain expected root name '%s'), but %s",
                    expSimpleName, p.getCurrentToken());
        }
        String actualName = p.getCurrentName();
        if (!expSimpleName.equalsIgnoreCase(actualName)) {
            ctxt.reportPropertyInputMismatch(rootType, actualName,
                    "Root name '%s' does not match expected ('%s') for type %s",
                    actualName, expSimpleName, rootType);
        }
        // ok, then move to value itself....
        p.nextToken();
        Object result = deser.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        // and last, verify that we now get matching END_OBJECT
        if (p.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            ctxt.reportWrongTokenException(rootType, JsonToken.END_OBJECT,
                    "Current token not END_OBJECT (to match wrapper object with root name '%s'), but %s",
                    expSimpleName, p.getCurrentToken());
        }
        if (config.isEnabled(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS)) {
            _verifyNoTrailingTokens(p, ctxt, rootType);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I copied the whole method from `ObjectMapper` class (version `2.10.1`) and in case you will upgrade `Jackson` version you need to check how implementation of this method looks like and replace it if needed.

Finally, you can use this new type in your test:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new CaseInsensitiveObjectMapper();
```

See also:

- [Is JSON case-sensitive?](https://www.quora.com/Is-JSON-case-sensitive)

Comment: This one is working fine but how ever I now have issues setting this new ObjectMapper globally and replace the default ObjectMapper.

Comment: @TechLearning, take a look at [Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring), [SpringBoot: Consume & Produce XML with a Custom Serializer + Deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184442/springboot-consume-produce-xml-with-a-custom-serializer-deserializer)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Your solution is working fine.

Comment: @TechLearning, I'g glad to hear that. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)